# Cannot send more than one table to an xlsx sheet using axlsx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axlsx

I am using axlsx_rails to produce reports in an application and I am attempting to write my first (ever) report using this gem.  The report is to allow the user to select a specific horse for the report and to output the horse and it's corresponding foals to the same sheet.  There is only one table (the Horse table) used for this purpose.   A horse's foals are found by querying the same table by the horse ID to either the Dam_id (if a mare) or the Sire field (if the horse is a Stallion). For simplicity, since the queries are working fine, I have not included the code on determining whether a mare or a stallion.

I am successful in outputting the horse to the spreadsheet, but although the foals are generated in the controller (I have used debugger to check), they are not being recognized in the sheet output.

Relevant code includes the following:

1. In the index_by_horse_report.html.erb, the horse is first selected and then:

   ```
       ....

     <%= link_to 'Download as horse_report.xlsx', index_by_horse_report_path(format: :xlsx ) %>

        ....
   ```
2. In the controller:

   ```
   def index_by_horse_report
      @horses = Horse.find_by_sql ["SELECT horses.id.....WHERE horses.id = ? ", @horse_id]
      @horses.each do |horse|
           @foalings = Horse.find_by_sql ["SELECT horses.id...... WHERE horses.sire_id = ?", horse.id]
      end
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html
         format.xlsx {
         response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="horse_report.xlsx"'
        }
      end
   end
   ```

The queries return 1 horse and 2 foals.

3. In the index_by_horse_report.xlsx.axlsx:

   ```
     wb = xlsx_package.workbook

     wb.add_worksheet(name: "Horse Report") do |sheet|
     sheet.add_row ["NAME","REGISTRATION#1","REGISTRATION#2", "SIRE", "DAM", "FOALING DATE", "BREED", "Colour", "GENDER", "OWNER", "DATE ARRIVED", "DATE LEFT", "NOTES" ]
     @horses.each do |horse|
         sheet.add_row [horse.horse_name,horse.registration_number,horse.registration_number_2, horse.sire_name, horse.dam_name, horse.foaling_date, horse.breed_name, horse.colour_name, horse.gender_name, horse.owner, horse.arrival_date, horse.date_left, horse.notes ]
         sheet.add_row [""]
         sheet.add_row ["FOALINGS"]
         sheet.add_row ["NAME","REGISTRATION#1","REGISTRATION#2", "SIRE", "SIRE/DAM", "FOALING DATE", "BREED", "Colour", "GENDER", "OWNER", "NOTES" ]
         if @foulings
            @foulings.each do |foul|
               sheet.add_row[foul.horse_name, foul.registration_number....]   
            end
          else
             sheet.add_row ["NO FOALS"]    
          end
        end
      end
     end
   ```

The excel spreadsheet shows:

First row:the column headings, 
Second row: Information for the horse selected, 
Third row: empty
Forth row:  FOALINGS
Fifth row: The foal headings
Sixth row: "NO FOALS"

Any help that can be given to help me discover why the foal information is not printed will be very much appreciated.

Thanking you in advance,

Comment: Just a question, is your variable really @foalings and not @foulings?

Comment: Plus, you might check for nil values in your foal row. Axlsx may not accept nil values for a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Noel.

This was just plain stupid.   It is foalings not foulings.   Lesson learned:  When doing something new, don't assume errors are due to a complex reason because of doing something new - check for the silly simple mistakes first!